# Selecting multiple entities using JPA 2.0 and Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I need to select multiples entities, mapped with JPA 2.0 and I am using Hibernate.

I'm validating a user log-in. I have a class `ClienteDTO` (aka Client) that extends an abstract class `Pessoa` (Person)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cliente")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id") 
public class ClienteDTO extends Pessoa implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 9057647385901589752L;

@OneToOne(mappedBy="cliente", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private LoginDTO login;

public ClienteDTO() {

}

    //get set
}
```

This is my class `Pessoa` ("Person" in Portuguese)

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@SequenceGenerator(name = "PESSOA_SEQ", sequenceName = "s_pessoa", initialValue = 1000, allocationSize = 20)
public abstract class Pessoa implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 5777501399478522675L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "PESSOA_SEQ")
@Column(unique = true, nullable = false, updatable = false)
private Long id;

private String nome;

private String email;

private String cpf;

public Pessoa() {

}

//get set

}
```

and this is the `Login` class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "login")
@NamedQueries({

    @NamedQuery(name = "obterUsuarioPorUsuarioSenha", query = "select l from LoginDTO where l.usuario = :usuarioParam and l.senha = :senhaParam"),

})
public class LoginDTO implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1718733412549158088L;

@Id
@Column(nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(generator = "gen")
@GenericGenerator(name = "gen", strategy = "foreign", parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "cliente"))
private Long idLoginCliente;

@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private ClienteDTO cliente;

@Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
private String usuario;

@Column(nullable = true)
private String senha;

public LoginDTO() {

}

// get set

}
```

My database has been generated like this:

Table ClienteDTO (Client)
    id = 1000

Table Pessoa (Person)

```
id = 1000
nome = ABC
email = xpto@xpto.xpto
cpf = 2131313124124
```

Table Login

```
idlogincliente = 1000
usuario (user) = admin
senha (password) = 8c48747q4s9c4q65
```

I'm using `@NamedQuery` at `Login`'s entity. I have an invocation of an EJB with the following method:

```
public LoginDTO efetuarLogin(LoginDTO usuarioDTO) throws Exception {

    Query q = em.createNamedQuery("obterUsuarioPorUsuarioSenha");
    q.setParameter("usuarioParam", usuarioDTO.getUsuario());
    q.setParameter("senhaParam", usuarioDTO.getSenha());

    try {
        return (LoginDTO) q.getSingleResult();
    } catch (NoResultException ne) {
        throw new NoResultException(ne.getMessage());
    }

}
```

The problem is that I'm not able to make the query. In this case, I'm getting the error

> Caused by: javax.persistence.NoResultException: No entity found for query

Is that because of FETCH? Or entity's relations is incorrect? Wrong query?

=====================================

Answer:

I am just an idiot. As you can see, I was encrypting my password.. And on my managed bean, I was NOT encrypting the password from form. Anyways, this thread may help people somehow. Thanks guys.

Comment: Try with `select l from LoginDTO l where l.usuario = :usuarioParam and l.senha = :senhaParam`. Also, don't name your entities XxxxDTO. They're not DTOs. Name them Xxxx, without any suffix.

Comment: yes, I know... I will change all of them. Anyways, thanks for your answer, but didn't solve. I'm getting the same error using select l from LoginDTO l where l.usuario = :usuarioParam and l.senha = :senhaParam

Comment: Check the values of the parameters (trailing white spaces, etc.), and the values in the database. Also check that you target the right database. If the query doesn't return anything, that simply means that no row matches with the query.

Comment: I have pasted all database's data related to these tables... and everything is fine with parameters. :(

Comment: Turn on SQL logging, see which query is generated by Hibernate, and execute it by yourself with the parameters.

Comment: I am just an idiot. As you can see, I was encrypting my password.. And on my managed bean, I was NOT encrypting the password from form. Anyways, this thread may help people somehow. Thanks guys.